# Install .NET Client Profile with autorun

Tags: .net, wpf, autorun, .net-client-profile

Hi All :
I develop an WPF windows application and i want to run it from the cd , so is there any way to make autorun cd to install .NET framework then run the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio (if you have Professional or better) to [create an installer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx) that will ensure the appropriate framework version (and any other dependencies) is installed (and at the end optionally launch the application).

Then you can [create an autorun](http://www.phdcc.com/shellrun/autorun.htm) file that will start this installer.

Comment: thanks for your replay , but the applicaton must run from cd and there is no install .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ClickOnce. This is available in the Express versions of Visual Studio.

The prerequisites, like the .NET Framework, are installed by the ClickOnce bootstrapper.

In the properties section of your project under 'Publish->Options->Deployment' check the 'For CD installations, automatically start Setup when CD is inserted'. So you just need to copy the generated files onto your cd.